# declaring and passing char array of different sizes correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I like to define a method that receives a char array of variable size.

This is my current definition:

```
+(int) findStartIndex: (NSData*)buffer  searchPattern: (char*) searchPattern;
```

And this is where I call it:

```
  const char a[] = {'a','b','c'};
  startIndex = [self findStartIndex:buffer  searchPattern: a];
```

and like this

```
  const char b[] = {'1','2'};
  startIndex = [self findStartIndex:buffer  searchPattern: b];
```

But I keep getting the compiler warning:

```
Sending 'const char[3]' to parameter of type 'char *' discards qualifiers
```

and

```
Sending 'const char[2]' to parameter of type 'char *' discards qualifiers
```

respectively.

How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the parameter you declared as char *, but const char [] is passed. It's a have a potential risk. you should the following changes. Do not have a warning when I tested.

```
+(int) findStartIndex: (NSData*)buffer  searchPattern: (const char*) searchPattern
```

Answer (score 1):

Qualifiers in C apply to the keyword on the left first, then fallback to the right next.  `const char arr[]` is not a constant reference to a char array, it's always of type char.  But, when you pass it to a method that takes a pointer to char, then you lose the const'ness of the type, and you get a warning.  (Hooray for obscure C stuff!)